# ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4, in order to enable client side validation in a view, should both keys `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` be true in web.config?

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can also be through the controller:

```
//Enable or Disable Client Side Validation at Application Level
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unobtrusive JavaScript is sort of optional, but since more controls and script libraries are using it I would leave that option enabled as well.

See **http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation**