# WebForm and MVC Project running side by side. Unobtrusive validation not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Webform project that I want to add MVC 5 to it so that the new stuff is developed is MVC.
One of the features that I like to use in MVC is the Unobtrusive client side validation. But I can't seem to make it work in the this scenario. The Validation works in the Server Side but does not work on the client side. By inspecting the tags I notice that the attributes are not being generated. I don't have any javascript error showing in the browser console.
If I do this in a pure MVC5 Project it works fine.
Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work? Am I missing something?

The way I have been testing is:

1. I create a webform project( using framework 4.5).
2. I add from NuGet MVC5 to the project.
3. Create an Area.
4. Add  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); to the Global.asax so that I can use Areas.
5. Add from NuGet:

   - jQuery Validation
   - Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation
6. Create a controller in the previous created Area and Add a View.
7. In the web.config of the View folder I add to the appSettings:
8. Then I create a Model and add the validation.

View Index:

```
@model Merda.Areas.Branchen.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TestModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop1)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop2)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Branchen/Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Valid");
        }
        else {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Error...");

        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Model Created:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }

}
```

Web.config inside the View folder created.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Merda" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:
I am using VS2012 Porfessional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write that keys in the main Web.config, not inside View folder. But also you can enable that validation in a per-controller basis, as seen in [ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033751/clientvalidationenabled-and-unobtrusivejavascriptenabled-in-mvc-4)

Comment: Thanks. Solved the problem.