# MVC Custom Client Validation date should be greater or equal than today

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am working with ASP.NET MVC4 and My requirement is that the date selected should be greater than or equal to today's date. I have created a custom validation attribute. It is working fine for server side but not for client side. Here is my code so far:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DateGreaterThanTodayAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly bool allowTodayDate;

    public DateGreaterThanTodayAttribute( bool allowTodayDate = false)
    {
        this.allowTodayDate = allowTodayDate;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is DateTime))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        // Compare values

        if ((DateTime)value > DateTime.Today)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (this.allowTodayDate && (DateTime)value == DateTime.Today)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "istodaydate"
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters["allowtodaydate"] = this.allowTodayDate;
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

**My client side code is:**

```
// Greater Than Today dates
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'istodaydate', ['allowtodaydate'], function (options) {
            options.rules['istodaydate'] = options.params.allowtodaydate;
            options.messages['istodaydate'] = options.message;
        });

$.validator.addMethod("istodaydate", function (value, element, param) {
    if (!value) return true;
    return (param.allowtodaydate) ?
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date()) <= $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value) :
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date()) < $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
}, '');
```

**And my Model is**

```
    [DateGreaterThanToday(true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(APMS.Resources.Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StartDateAfterEndDate")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.QCP.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "SurveyInterval_FromDateRequired")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: "not working" is far too vague.

Comment: You have this options enable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033751/clientvalidationenabled-and-unobtrusivejavascriptenabled-in-mvc-4

Comment: @DLeh No problem. Just the client validation is not working. Server validation is working. No error thrown. :(

Comment: @TotPeRo Yes they are enabled.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid other type of validation works in your project? not this custom. you have include the jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js javascript files in your layout?

Comment: Yes other validations work perfectly. and These files are also included in my project.