# Set a ViewContext property on every partial view of the current ViewResult to disable jquery unobtrusive validation HTML attribute generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a project I'm working on, I need to disable jquery unobtrusive validation on some pages and enable it on others. In the current state of the project, the validation is turned on everywhere and has to be disabled on some pages. I know if I have to disable it once I'm in the controller.

I already conditionally import the plug-in's javascript files, so there is no unnecessary download. However, my custom HtmlHelpers that use the default HtmlHelpers still generate HTML attributes that are exclusively used by jquery unobtrusive validation. If I use `Html.EnableClientValidation(false);` or `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = false;` on a specific partial view, the attributes are not generated *for that specific partial view* - exactly what I want. <strike>But, because the views are compiled backwards, from the most nested to the main view, this means I would need to set use the `Html.EnableClientValidation` or `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` in *almost every view*, which is not an option.</strike>. Correction: I need tried using `Html.EnableClientValidation()` in the layout of the view, which is called last (after the view and partials). If I place the `Html.EnableClientValidation()` in the view and not the layout, it will be correctly set. I need this to be done before I get to the view, to avoif writing that in every view.

So my question is, how do I get the effect of an in-view `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` in every view? Could I set `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` before the view generation, to get it on every page? From what I researched, I would possibly need to derive from the razor engine? Is there no easier solution, perhaps through some `ActionFilter` or directly from a controller?

Comment: Setting `ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled` on the main view should pass that value to all child views, from my testing. Do you need some partials with validation and some without within the same view?

Comment: If I set ClientValidationEnabled in a view, its partials do not get the same value for me. If I put breakpoints in the partial and the view, the partial will hit it before the parent view. I don't need it to be changed from partial to partial. It should be a "parent" page decision. I believe I found a possible solution, testing at the moment.

Comment: I get the exact opposite, the main view hits the breakpoint first. What method are you using to call/render the partial view?

Comment: `Html.Partial()`. Is it possible you're using .NET Core? Maybe it's different there too, I'm not using core.

Comment: You're right! My mistake. Correction: The Layout is called last. The view is called first, then it's partials then the layout is called. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: setting `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;` in a controller will set it in all ViewContexts that will be container in the `ViewResult` or `PartialViewResult`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033751/clientvalidationenabled-and-unobtrusivejavascriptenabled-in-mvc-4)